# Assigning a removable singularity a value.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, singularity

I am having trouble with the following question:

Given a function $h(z)=\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$, where $f$ is holomorphic and has a zero at $z_0$ of order $n$, while $g$ also is holomorphic with a zero at $z_0$ of order $m$, show that for $n\geq m$, the function $h$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$, and that
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}h(z) = \frac{f^{(m)}(z_0)}{g^{(m)}(z_0)}.$$

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried power series?

Comment: I did, but I could not make anything of it.

Comment: Please show us your attempt, so we can see where your difficulty is.

Comment: You can apply L' Hopital to the power series m-times to get the answer

Comment: I thought about using L' Hopital m-times, but I was unsure whether that was possible for complex function. Do I need an argument for why I can use it? @aritracb

Comment: @saulspatz I tried to differentiate the power series of the functions f and g m-times, just to see what I was left with, but didn't know what to do then.

Comment: Actually proving L'Hopital  for holomorphic functions is trivial. Anyway you don't even need that just cancel $z^m$ from the power series of $f$ and $g$.Because of the order of the zeroes $z^n$ factors out from $f$'s power series at $0$ and $z^m$ factors out from that of $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps will help.

1. You can use power series expansion at $z_0$. Why?
2. The coefficients of a term $(z-z_0)^k$ is $a_k=\frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!}$. How?
3. As a result you will obtain $f(z)=(z-z_0)^m(a_m+O(z-z_0))$. Check this.
4. Conclude.